# Automatic transcompilation in Netbeans or otherwise

Tags: html, ubuntu, netbeans, compiler-construction, handlebars.js

My new project aims to use multiple transcompiled languages, in-particular, SASS, CoffeeScript and Handlebars.  I am using Netbeans as my IDE and PHP (Zend) as my backend.

I found pre-existing Netbeans plugins for CoffeeScript and SASS, to auto-compile down to javascript and CSS, respectively.  However, I cannot find a plugin to auto-precompile my Handlebars templates to javascript.

My ideal solution would be to configure Netbeans to re-compile .handlebars files whenever they are saved (which is what the CoffeeScript and SASS plugins do for their respective filetypes already).

Another solution is for some kind of separate 'watcher' process that can watch a folder for file changes and run the handlebars transcompiler automatically.

Does anyone know any simple tools/plugins already out there? or can give any hints on how I could configure Netbeans? or how to write a little watcher script (my *nix scripting knowledge is poor)?

Answer (score 0):

A mishmash of various code snippets has led me to this inelegant but working 'watcher' script:

```
  
inotifywait -mr --format '%e/%w%f' . | (
  while read data;do 
    event="${data%/*}";
    if [ "$event" = "MODIFY/." ]; then  
      filename="${data##*/}"
      extension="${filename##*.}"
      filename="${filename%.*}"
       if [ "$extension" = "hbs" ]; then
        handlebars "$filename.$extension" -a -f "$filename".js; 
        echo $filename updated; 
      fi;
    fi;
  done; 
)
exit 0;
```